# Translate ISO 8601 UTC time format to hh:mm of EST

Tags: c#, json, datetime, linq-to-objects, utc

I have a list of objects that I de-serialized from a json string that have a start/end time field expressed in UTC time. Eg: "2016-08-22T15:30:00Z" (which is 11:30AM EST). I need to transform the time to a user-friendly format (e.g, "11:30 AM") on the server before sending down the list in JSON for displaying on a web page. Is there a c# function that will help me accomplish this transform the time property to the desired result?

code example:

```
    public class Event
    {
        public int EventId { get; set; } //1
        public string Name { get; set; } //Karate class
        public string StartAt { get; set; } //2016-08-22T15:30:00Z
        public string EndAt { get; set; } //2016-08-22T16:30:00Z
    }

    public class Events
    {
        public List<Event> Events {get; set;}

    }

    //de-serialize from json string
    string eventsForToday = "{}" //some json string from api
    var eventList = (Events)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(eventsForToday, typeof(Events));

    foreach (var item in eventList.Events)
    {
        //needs to be 11:30AM instead of 2016-08-22T15:30:00Z
        Console.WriteLine (item.StartAt) 
    }
```

I know that the logic is whatever the UTC time is it should be offset by 4 (or 5 depending on time of year). But what is the most straight-forward way to modify the objects? Is there a way to project a new list with the format changed, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each string into a DateTime.  DateTime has a method ToLocalTime() that will do the conversion for you as long as you specify the Kind property of the DateTime.  For example,

```
foreach (var item in eventList.Events)
{
    DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(item.StartAt), DateTimeKind.Utc);
    Console.WriteLine (timeUtc.ToLocalTime()); //Add .ToShortTimeString() if you just want the time (and not the date)
}
```

However, since your string has a trailing "Z", you should just be able to use `Convert.ToDateTime(item.StartAt).ToWhateverString()`